# No Background image in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background, background-image, shadow

I'm working on a site,

seen here: http://handsomeavatar.com/test111/

and I can't get the background of the menu to load in IE (8).

Can anyone help me?

```
CSS 
.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 8px 6px -6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
box-shadow:         0 8px 6px -6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
}

#menu {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -5px;  
width: 800px; 
background: transparent url(img/cloudy.jpg); 
height: 43px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

and html

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix"> 
<div id="menu" class="shadow">
<ul id="navigation">
```

It seems to be happening anywhere I used the .shadow element.

The backgrounds aren't showing up, even if I delete the class.
The other items on the page load, but even after deleting:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
 zoom: 1;
```

The menu image still does not show up (Can't see the background).

With the "filter:" on, all you see is shadows and nothing on top.

The problem or question needing answered is why is the background not loading.

javascript as follows:

```
function navigation_open()
{   navigation_canceltimer();
navigation_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

function navigation_close()
{   if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function navigation_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(navigation_close, timeout);}

function navigation_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
{   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
    closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#navigation > li').bind('mouseover', navigation_open);
$('#navigation > li').bind('mouseout',  navigation_timer);});'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
```

It creates an ugly effect and does not let people see the menu. Regarding to the background, there is something adding inline style to the menu element. Maybe a JS file. By the way, the menu is on a white background, so you don't have to use background:transparent.

Comment: Try removing the -moz-border-radius. Firefox now support border radius normally, and I've heard that in some cases this -moz-border-radius creates problems in IE8.

Comment: I deleted the -moz-border-radius, no change. the backgrounds load on refresh but then turn white. I'm not sure what i'm missing?

Comment: It is not your javascript. It must be a plugin, or something. Never used .htc so, I don't know if it could be the problem. Try removing js and behavours until it works in order to know what is going on.

Comment: Looks like the .htc was the culprit.